# continuous memory allocation for structure with pointer fields

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a structure like

`struct mystruct {
      int x;
      int size_of_data;
      int *data;
}`

and I want to allocate memory at continuous memory area for mystruct and the data.
I tried `malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)+size_of_data*sizeof(int))` but I got a segmentation fault.

I also tried:

```
struct mystruct *var = malloc(sizeof(*var))
var->data = malloc(size_of_data*sizeof(int))
```

but the problem is that the allocator does not guarantee that the `var->data` will be contiuous to the whole struct, but I strongly need to be continuous. Any ideas?

`mystruct` needs to stay unchanged

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)+size_of_data*sizeof(int))` should work.SHow yr code and the error

Comment: Your first attempt is workable , you must have made a mistake somewhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You had the right allocation, but you have to initialize your `data` member to point to the `int`s.

```
struct mystruct *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)+size_of_data*sizeof(int));
assert(s);
s->data = (int *)(s+1);
/* now can use data member like an array */
```

Alternatively, you can modify your definition of `mystruct` to make `data` a flexible array. Then, `data` will just be at the beginning of the `int`s that you allocated space for.

```
struct mystruct {
  int x;
  int size_of_data;
  int data[];
};

struct mystruct *s;
s = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)+size_of_data*sizeof(int));
assert(s);
/* now can use data member like an array */
```

Comment: @user3528438 It won't, because stronger alignment satisfies weaker alignment requirements.

Comment: @2501 he probably meant weaker alignment . Which won't happen for this particular struct.

Comment: @user3528438 Can `sizeof( struct ... )` ever return a value that's smaller than the alignment requirements of that `struct`?  If so, then things do get interesting...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Footnote 106 in C.2011.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a "flexible array member".  Per **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 18, of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   flexible array member . In most situations, the  flexible  array 
>   member  is  ignored.  In  particular, the  size  of  the  structure 
>   is  as  if  the flexible  array  member  were  omitted  except  that 
>   it  may  have  more  trailing  padding  than the omission would imply.
>   Howev er, when a . (or
>   -> ) operator has a left operand that is (a  pointer  to)  a  structure  with  a  flexible  array  member  and  the  right  operand 
>   names  that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with
>   the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the
>   structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the
>   array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this
>   would differ from that of the replacement array.  If this array would
>   have no elements, it behaves as if it  had  one  element  but  the 
>   behavior  is  undefined  if  any  attempt  is  made  to  access  that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.

Example:

```
typedef struct flexible
{
    size_t len;
    char data[];
} flexible_t;

...

size_t thisMuchData = getAmountOfData();
flexible_t *ptr = malloc( sizeof( *ptr ) + thisMuchData );
ptr->len = thisMuchData;
memcpy( ptr->data, dataSource, thisMuchData );
```